# Sencha nested list like in Firefox

Tags: list, firefox, webkit, sencha-touch

I would like to know, if there is any way to create Sencha like nested list in Firefox and IE?

Since it cannot be made with Sencha (due to not supported web kit in FF and IE) I assume there must be a way to create something that looks like Sencha nested list in Firefox.

best

Answer (score 0):

jQueryMobile nested lists work in IE and Firefox